# Error 325 Unknown error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome, localhost

In Chrome 21.0.1180.75 on OS X 10.8, my Rails app fails to load:
([Image of error page](http://cl.ly/image/0x23082o3h24))

The text is below, if you don't want to load the image:

---

This webpage is not available

The webpage at `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Error 325 (net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG): Unknown error.

---

It fails when I try to access it using `localhost:3000`, `127.0.0.1:3000`, and `0.0.0.0:3000`, but if I access using my local IP address, it's fine. This only happens in Chrome. Firefox, Safari, and Opera are able to load localhost perfectly fine.

I've already cleared cache and cookies, to no avail. Any ideas on what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/N0zL6FXq2SE%5B1-25%5D:

- Storing a too large array
- Use of a header redirect during logic flow
- Un-setting a cookie array

See if your code is triggering any of these situations.

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't happen when I push the same code to our staging server. It also doesn't happen to the other developers on my team.

Comment: Are you all using the same version of Chrome?

Comment: I just rolled back to 21.0.1180.57, still doesn't work. Another big difference that I neglected to mention is that I'm on OS X 10.8, but they're on 10.7.

Comment: Thanks for your patience :) This is happening for every page, so it also happens for the splash page, which doesn't load any arrays, let alone a large one. The splash page does possibly have a header redirect, but since I'm not logged in, that doesn't happen (dev server logs confirm this). I tried changing the logic for the splash page to `render :text => "ok", :layout => false`.

Comment: `Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-09 10:06:10 -0700`
`Processing by PublicController#homepage as HTML`
`Rendered text template (0.0ms)`
`Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 10.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

Comment: I just started up VirtualBox and used Chrome 20.0.1132.57 m. `10.0.2.2:3000` doesn't work :(

Comment: Hmm.. could your install be corrupt?  Try clearing your cache and browser history then reinstall.  That wouldn't really explain the VM not working though unless it's not reaching the local server or being blocked.

Comment: Wow at myself :( The `render :text => 'ok'` is successful after I kill the server and the bash session. Curling localhost gives me `curl: (27) Avoided giant realloc for header (max is 102400)!`, so I'll look into the headers that are being sent. Thanks for the help so far! :)

Comment: At last! Found the problem. [http://miniprofiler.com/](http://miniprofiler.com/)'s X-MiniProfiler-Ids was taking up a huge amount of data. Thanks for the suggestions and bearing with me, Luke!

Comment: Every refresh added information to X-MiniProfiler-Ids, until the response header was just obscenely large.